# Java: Produce larger random numbers

Tags: java, random, int, long-integer, factorization

I created a simple prime factorization program in java for the fun of it. Right now I am using the Random class and nextLong() method to assign "temp" a random number ranging in the quintillions and factors it amazingly quickly. What data type or algorithm or method should I use to obtain significantly larger values?

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class factor {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Random gen = new Random();
   String factors = "";
   long temp = 0;
   String hello = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type a random number(Must be smaller than 4,611,686,018,427,387,904), or type 1 for a random large number.");
  temp = Long.parseLong(hello);
   if(temp < 2)
   temp = Math.abs(gen.nextLong());
   long temp2 = temp;
   System.out.println("  The factors of   \n\n  " + temp2 + "   are:");
   System.out.println("");
   while(temp != 1){
       //System.out.print(temp);
   for(long ii = 2; ii <= (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(temp))); ii++){
  // if(ii%12345 == 0)
 // System.out.println(temp + " " + ii + " " + factors);
        if(temp%ii == 0){
            factors = factors + "  " + ii;
           // System.out.println(temp + " " + ii + " " + factors);
            temp = temp/ii;
            ii = temp + 1;       
  }else{
   if(ii == Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(temp))){
   factors = factors + " " + temp;
            System.out.println(factors);
            temp = 1;
            ii = temp + 1;   
   }}
        }
   }}}
```

Comment: If you used a quantum computer you still wouldn't be able to get the largest random number

Comment: It factors it quickly because it's wrong. I am not sure you know what you're doing in this code. `if(temp%ii == 0)` then ... `ii = temp +1` Why? What output do you get for the number 81 e.g.? Do you get "3 3 3 3" ?

Comment: `BigInteger` comes to mind...

Comment: I don't understand the question,  there is no "largest random number". Do you mean largest that will fit in a double?  Or largest that can be represented by the computer or .....? (BigInterger only has size limits based on availabille memory)

Comment: try running it with the input 81 peter, it will work. I have factored numbers like 5684275247958 in a few seconds and re-multiplied the prime factors back together and it worked.

Comment: OK, I will, you got me curious :)

Comment: OK, I take this back. Sorry.

Comment: Haha :) Apology accepted. Yeah my goal in this question is I want to be able to factor bigger numbers that quintillions. Because a Long can only hold 2^63 because it is a 64 bit data type, so how could I get bigger values? Takendarkk, I thought of using BigInteger but how would I generate a **random** BigInteger?

Comment: I will try some more, let me find you a few bad examples.

Comment: Try running on this example: `temp = 4611686018427387903L;` It's not as fast as you think.

Comment: Try also: `temp = 924961025514621481L`.

Comment: 4611686018427387903 took 20 seconds to factor on my computer. I'd say that is pretty good considering it has 3 HUGE prime factors and has 19 digits. I did around 200 tests the average speed was around 5 seconds for random numbers with more than 17 digits.

Comment: Well, if you think this is good OK ;) I think it's not. There are better ways, I think. This is a pretty straightforward algorithm you've implemented. Try also `5075762304003453001` and `4591670831448457501`.

Comment: "Don't fix what isn't broken" But out of curiosity what would be a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization

Comment: http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM

Comment: This is a good paper describing several factorization techniques: http://www.connellybarnes.com/documents/factoring.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the random constructor for BigInteger:

```
BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)
```

If you need any more information, you can check out the API: [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's useless and sadly coded. You can play with big number and say it's fast but the point is not "how big is my number"... it's "how bigs are the factors". Just take a big prime number and sleep until your code works.

For the big number generation... there is BigInteger

```
public class Factor {

    public static BigInteger generateBigOne() {
        final Random random = new Random();

        long loop = random.nextLong();
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            result += random.nextLong();
        }
        return new BigInteger(result);
    }
}
```